# Mobile web page

Tags: android, css, reactjs, browser

I have a mobile web chat app as shown screenshot
[image]
, I have a textbox at the bottom of screen which is in footer and on android browsers, the textbox is not coming up on focus whereas in ios its working fine. Can any one help. developement in ReactJs.

footer: {

```
zIndex: 2,
bottom: 0,
boxSizing: "border-box",
left: 0,
position: "absolute",
right: 0,
background: "#fff",
position: "relative",
padding: "0 10px",
boxShadow: "0px -1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.12)"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have used the **position** property twice one is `absolute` and another is `relative`.
Try using only one value and see the result. Hope it will work.

Comment: position: "relative", always override the first one.

Comment: try using **absolute** making the parent element **relative**. If you don't use the value of **top/left/right/bottom** There's no point of using relative [unless you use positioning in the child element]

Answer (score 0):

I just used a simple logic by using jquery
Here I am Use HTML :

```
<div></div>
<footer>
  <input type="text"/>
</footer>
```

Here I am use Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').click(function(){
       $('footer').removeClass('make-top');
   });  
   $('footer > input').click(function(){
       $('footer').addClass('make-top');
   });
});
```

Here the CSS :

```
div{
  height:200px;
}

footer{
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px -1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    transition:.5s;
} 

@media (max-width:600px){
  .make-top{
    bottom:100px;// Mention the keyboard layout actual height.
  }
}
```

Just take the keycode while the back button pressed : and remove this class via jquery..

I hope this will help.

Comment: I dont think we can use this. as the size of keyboard varies with diff mobile model. also this web page is used in desktop also

Answer (score 0):

Issues fixed. my main div when media max-width: 767px i was giving height 100% !important. this was stopping android webpages not to show textbox as the height was important and i removed it. but this was not causing issue in IOS browsers. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLPy5.png